# Simple Keyboard Remap Question

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I want to use my Caps Lock key as Super+A key, but remapping solutions that I found do not support the feature. Do you know how to command something by pressing the specific key?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a combination of two keystrokes, `xcape` may be a solution. the Ubuntu [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xcape.1.html) explains how to do it.

So a command like this

> xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Super|A'

might be a solution.

`/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` includes all the relevant keystroke definitions